# Where clause for list of list

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code that filters me the LabelType which contains "abcd".
list1 is a List that contains List of Parts (that contains string LabelType)

```
foreach (var elem in list1)
{
    elem.Parts = elem.Parts.Where(p => p.LabelType != "abcd").ToList();
}
```

How can I convert all of it in one line using linq?

Comment: Try all  : elem.Parts = elem.Parts.Where(p => p.All(x => x.LabelType != "abcd")).ToList();  You can also use elem.Parts.Where(p => !p.Contains("abcd").ToList()

Comment: "all of it in one line" is not a real requirement. Changing the elem(ent)s of a list while iterating it is ... a bad idea. You should be clearer about the expected result: a changed list-of-lists, a new list(-of-lists) , a list of strings, ... ?

Comment: @jdweng, what you said is the same thing I asked. It doesn't put all code in one line, since I have to return list1 and not elem.Parts

Comment: The code returns a List object.  So if you have a list of string I usually use string.Join(",", string[]) to flatten the list.  This will create a comma separate string.

Comment: solved and got it. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to select the items you could use `Where` to filter and apply the `Any` to check the occurrence of the condition you want `(p.LabelType != "abcd")`:

```
var result = list1.Where(x => x.Parts.Any(p => p.LabelType != "abcd"))
                  .ToList();
```

Now, if you want to modify the content of the `Parts` property it is not a good pratice to change the element that is part of your loop scope. You could try it:

```
var result = list1.Select(x => 
                   { 
                     x.Parts = x.Parts.Where(p => p.LabelType != "abcd")).ToList();
                     return x;
                   })
                  .ToList();
```

In the Select scope you can perform changes on the element (x) but [inside of this  there is a loop](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#L47), so, the result if the same of using the foreach but in design level it is one command. There is no performance gain here.

Comment: actually, this returns me a list of elements that does not include "abcd" label. What I asked is to filter only the field LabelType that contains "abcd".

Comment: my code returns me 5 elements in list1 (where LabelType field does not contain "abcd") and your code returns me 2 elements with no "abcd" in LabelType). Different results

Comment: It works how I've expected. i'm doing this just to practice with linq.  Thank you!

Comment: In the `Select` scope you can perform changes on the element (`x`) but inside of this, there is a loop, so, the result if the same of using the `foreach` but in design level it is one command. There is no performance gain here.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your explanations and help.

Comment: Nice, remember to mark it as an answer to help other users on the future :)